# Table mail layout styles are not shown correctly in outlook

Tags: html, css, email, layout, outlook

I am creating a mail layout with tables but I am struggling to obtain the desired result in outlook.

I am using https://app.postdrop.io/ to create the layout, with postdrop I can send it to a mail, so I am testing it in gmail and outlook. In gmal looks all okay, as I want. But in outlook the styles are not shown correctly and I don't know what to try anymore.

This is the code I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Mai layout</title>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0">
    <table
      style="
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Arial;
        padding: 16px;
      "
    >
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table
            style="
              border: 1px solid #e7e8e8;
              border-radius: 8px;
              padding: 16px;
              margin-bottom: 16px;
            "
            width="100%"
          >
            <tr>
              <td
                colspan="2"
                style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: 700; color: #006899;"
              >
                Demo text
              </td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
              <td style="width:0">
                <img
                 src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather-5/24/star-16.png"
                 alt="location"
                 style="vertical-align:middle; width:16px; height:16px"
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <span style="
                  color: #555c5e;
                  font-size: 14px;
                  font-weight: 400;
                  line-height: 22px;
                ">
                   Demo text
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img
                  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather-5/24/star-16.png"
                  alt="work mode"
                  style="vertical-align:middle; width:16px; height:16px"
                />
              </td>
              <td
                style="
                  color: #555c5e;
                  font-size: 14px;
                  font-weight: 400;
                  line-height: 22px;
                "
              >
                Demo text
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img
                  src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather-5/24/star-16.png"
                  alt="location"
                 style="vertical-align:middle; width:16px; height:16px"
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <span style="
                  color: #555c5e;
                  font-size: 14px;
                  font-weight: 400;
                  line-height: 22px;
                ">
                   Demo text
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                <table style="width: 350px">
                  <tr>
                    <td
                      style="
                        border-radius: 100px;
                        padding: 4px 8px;
                        background-color: #f5f5f6;
                        color: #3c4447;
                        width: 1px;
                        font-weight: 700;
                        font-size: 12px;
                      "
                    >
                      Demo text
                    </td>
                    <td
                      style="
                        border-radius: 100px;
                        padding: 4px 8px;
                        background-color: #f5f5f6;
                        color: #3c4447;
                        width: 1px;
                        font-weight: 700;
                        font-size: 12px;
                      "
                    >
                      <img
                       src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather-5/24/star-16.png"
                        alt="disability"
                       style="vertical-align:middle; width:16px; height:16px"
                      />
                     Demo text
                    </td>
                    <td
                      style="
                        border-radius: 100px;
                        padding: 4px 8px;
                        background-color: #f5f5f6;
                        color: #3c4447;
                        width: 1px;
                        font-weight: 700;
                        font-size: 12px;
                      "
                    >
                      <img
                        src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather-5/24/star-16.png"
                        alt="disability"
                        style="vertical-align:middle; width:16px; height:16px"
                      />
                      Demo text
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is what I see in postdrop while I am creating the layout:

[image]

This is how it looks like in gmail:

[image]

but this in outlook:

[image]

What can I do to make outlook get the styles and display it like gmail, is it possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, simply I added another table inside to separate the first and second block. This is the improved code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Demo text</title>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0">
   
    <table style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; font-family: Arial">
      <tr>
        <td
          style="border: 1px solid #e7e8e8; border-radius: 8px; padding: 16px"
        >
          <table style="margin-bottom: 16px" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td
                colspan="2"
                style="
                  font-size: 20px;
                  font-weight: 700;
                  color: #006899;
                  padding-bottom: 4px;
                "
              >
                Demo text
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img
                   src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather-5/24/star-16.png"
                  alt="location"
                  style="width: 16px; height: 16px"
                />
              </td>
              <td
                style="
                  color: #555c5e;
                  font-size: 14px;
                  font-weight: 400;
                  line-height: 22px;
                  padding-bottom: 5.5px;
                "
              >
                Demo text
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img
                   src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather-5/24/star-16.png"
                  alt="work"
                  style="width: 16px; height: 16px"
                />
              </td>
              <td
                style="
                  color: #555c5e;
                  font-size: 14px;
                  font-weight: 400;
                  line-height: 22px;
                  padding-bottom: 5.5px;
                "
              >
                Demo text
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img
                   src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather-5/24/star-16.png"
                  alt="business"
                  style="width: 16px; height: 16px"
                />
              </td>
              <td
                style="
                  color: #555c5e;
                  font-size: 14px;
                  font-weight: 400;
                  line-height: 22px;
                  padding-bottom: 5.5px;
                "
              >
               Demo text
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td
                style="
                  border-radius: 100px;
                  padding: 4px 8px;
                  background-color: #f5f5f6;
                  color: #3c4447;
                  font-weight: 700;
                  font-size: 12px;
                "
              >
                <span>Demo text</span>
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td
                style="
                  border-radius: 100px;
                  padding: 4px 8px;
                  background-color: #f5f5f6;
                  color: #3c4447;
                  font-weight: 700;
                  font-size: 12px;
                "
              >
                <img
                   src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather-5/24/star-16.png"
                  alt="disability"
                  style="vertical-align: middle"
                />
                <span>Demo text</span>
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td
                style="
                  border-radius: 100px;
                  padding: 4px 8px;
                  background-color: #f5f5f6;
                  color: #3c4447;
                  font-weight: 700;
                  font-size: 12px;
                "
              >
                <img
                   src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather-5/24/star-16.png"
                  alt="disability"
                  style="vertical-align: middle"
                />
                <span>Demo text</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks in outlook:

[image]